# jQuery UI autocomplete: how to send post data?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

From [jQuery UI site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) (veiw source):

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
            "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
    }
});
```

So as I see there is no options how to make ajax request with ***post data*** to the `"search.php"`.

But I need to do that to send some filter from previous input field (current field:
*city*, previous field: *country*).

How to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try changing the source to be a method which uses $.post:

```
$("#birds").autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    $.post("search.php", request, response);
  },
  ...
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({ 
source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:"search.php",
  data: request,
  success: response,
  dataType: 'json'
});
  }
}, {minLength: 3 });

//-------------------------
//search.php - example with request from DB

//


 $link = mysql_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_login, $mysql_password)
        or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die("Could not select database");
     mysql_set_charset('utf8'); 

$req = "SELECT mydata FROM $mysql_table WHERE mydata LIKE '".$_REQUEST['term']."%' ORDER BY mydata ASC";
$query = mysql_query($req);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $results[] = array('label' => $row['mydata']);
}


echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same need and no single example from stackoverflow was working properly.

By testing diffrent authors contributions and tweaking here and there the below example is most likely what anyone would be looking for in an autocomplete that

1. Send out POST request.
2. Does not require tweaking the main autocomplete UI.
3. Sends out multiple parameters for evaluation.
4. Retrieves data from a database PHP file.

All credit is to the many persons whom i used their sample answers
to make this working sample.

```
        $( "#employee_name" ).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"employees.php",
        data: {term:request.term,my_variable2:"variable2_data"},
        success: response,
        dataType: 'json',
        minLength: 2,
        delay: 100
            });
        }});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked well for me. I needed some custom data, so I pulled the search "term" `term: request.term` out of the request as follows:

```
  jQuery('.some-autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {action: 'some_content_search', type: type, term: request.term}, response, 'json');
    },
    minLength: 2,
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do this more simple with **type: "post"**:

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    type: "post"
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
            "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no such option or method as `type` in Autocomplete API: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/