# how would i remove term parameter from jquery autocomplete ajax URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When going to search customer name, jQuery automatically appends `cstmr-prfsnl-ajax-search.php?term=[search value]` but I want to replace term with customer. please help me.

```
$("#ccpd_name").autocomplete({
  source: "cstmr-prfsnl-ajax-search.php",
  minLength: 1
});
```

Comment: This is how the data is transferred - through the URL in a GET request. Why is that a problem? If you want to change the behaviour you'd need to use POST instead, which would involve amending the options you provide to the autocomplete library, and also how the PHP file receives the data

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300381/jquery-ui-autocomplete-how-to-send-post-data) for how to make the POST request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this :

```
$("#ccpd_name").autocomplete({
     source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
             url: "cstmr-prfsnl-ajax-search.php",
             data: { customer: request.term },
             dataType: "json",
             success: response,
             error: function () {
                 response([]);
             }
         });
     });
});
```

> cstmr-prfsnl-ajax-search.php?customer=[search value]

Comment: hope it helps @subhankar-dutta

Answer (score 2):

you can also omit the data field like so:

```
$("#ccpd_name").autocomplete({
 source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
         url: "cstmr-prfsnl-ajax-search.php?customer=" + request.term,
         dataType: "json",
         success: response,
         error: function () {
             response([]);
         }
     });
 });
```

});